# SQL sort by subnet then by name

Tags: sql

I have an SQL query as follows

```
Select Top 1000000 tsysOS.Image As icon,
  tblAssets.AssetID,
  tblAssets.AssetName,
  tblAssets.Domain,
  tblAssets.Username,
  tblAssets.IPAddress,
  tblAssets.Lastseen,
  tblAssets.Lasttried
From tblAssets
  Inner Join tblAssetCustom On tblAssets.AssetID = tblAssetCustom.AssetID
  Inner Join tsysOS On tsysOS.OScode = tblAssets.OScode
Where tblAssets.AssetID Not In (Select Top 1000000 tblSoftware.AssetID
      From tblSoftware Inner Join tblSoftwareUni On tblSoftwareUni.SoftID =
          tblSoftware.softID
      Where tblSoftwareUni.softwareName Like '%LsAgent%') And tblAssetCustom.State = 1
Order By tblAssets.Domain Desc,
  tblAssets.IPAddress,
  tblAssets.AssetName
```

Currently it sorts by domain, then by IP, then by name.

How can I get it so that it sorts by just the subnet to the 3rd section, then by name.

Ex:

- all IPs with 10.0.0.x first (sorted by name)
- then all of 10.10.1.x (sorted by name)
- then all of 10.10.2.x (sorted by name) and so on

Currently it sorts by IP address completely, making the name sort irrelevant.

---

#### Edit:

Example data: This is what it currently outputs.  Sorted by Domain, then IP, then AssetName.  The IP sort makes the AssetName sort irrelevant.

```
(All columns are varchar)
AssetName   Domain  UsrName IPAddress 
COM-664     RSB     admin   10.0.1.194
COM-500     RSB     admin   10.0.1.196
COM-413     RSB     admin   10.0.1.200
COM-670     RSB     admin   10.0.2.45
COM-524     RSB     admin   10.0.2.80
COM-608     RSB     admin   10.0.2.83
COM-565     RSB     admin   10.0.3.129
COM-544     RSB     admin   10.0.3.13
COM-696     RSB     admin   10.0.3.15
```

Desired result: (sorted by subnet up to 10.0.X, then by AssetName)

```
AssetName   Domain  UsrName IPAddress 
COM-413     RSB     admin   10.0.1.200
COM-500     RSB     admin   10.0.1.196
COM-664     RSB     admin   10.0.1.194
COM-524     RSB     admin   10.0.2.80
COM-608     RSB     admin   10.0.2.83
COM-670     RSB     admin   10.0.2.45
COM-544     RSB     admin   10.0.3.13
COM-565     RSB     admin   10.0.3.129
COM-696     RSB     admin   10.0.3.15
```

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and an appropriate database tag.  What is the data type, for instance, of the ip address?

Comment: @GordonLinoff added example data.  The syntax is generic SQL afaik, used in LanSweeper.

Comment: . . If my answer works, then your database is SQL Server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your syntax looks like SQL Server.

Assuming that the IP address is stored as a string, then SQL Server offers a very bespoke function called [`parsename()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/parsename-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) which basically does what you want:

```
order by try_convert(int, parsename(tblAssets.IPAddress, 4)),
         try_convert(int, parsename(tblAssets.IPAddress, 3)),
         try_convert(int, parsename(tblAssets.IPAddress, 2)),
         tblAssets.AssetName
```